# Вывод в TextBox

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

Пытаюсь сделать вывод в TextBox

```
System::Void CursGraf::MyForm::buttonRead_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Данные №" + Convert::ToString(i + 1);
        [i].Print();
    }
    
    return System::Void();
}
```

Вот сам Print

```
void Data1::Print()
{
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Марка авто: " + marc.marca;
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Дата изготовления: " + date.day + " " + date.month + " " + date.year;
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Расход топлива по городу: " + fuel.in;
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Расход топлива за городом: " + fuel.out;
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Состояние авто: " + condition.condition;
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Цена авто: " + price.prices;
}
```

Когда пишу не видит textBox1 хотя в другом действии всё работает, думал что проблема в том что код не там написан и попытался перенести, после этого стало видеть textBox1 и перестало видеть marc.marca и тд.
Как вывести данные правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался что к чему и как заставить видить textBox, вот что получилось в итоге

```
System::Void CursGraf::MyForm::buttonRead_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    textBox1->Clear();
    n = _actions;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Данные №" + Convert::ToString(i + 1);
        d[i].Print(textBox1);
    }
    return System::Void();
}


    void Print(Data1* d, int n, System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1)
{
    n = _actions;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        d[i].Print(textBox1);
    }
}


void Data1::Print(System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1)
{
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Марка авто: " + gcnew System::String(marc.marca.c_str());
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Дата изготовления: " + date.day.ToString() + "." + date.month.ToString() + "." + date.year.ToString();
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Расход топлива по городу: " + fuel.in.ToString() + " " + "Литров";
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Расход топлива за городом: " + fuel.out.ToString() + " " + "Литров";
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Состояние авто: " + gcnew System::String(condition.condition.c_str());
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "Цена авто: " + price.prices.ToString() + " " + "Валюта";
    textBox1->Text += Environment::NewLine + "____________________________";
}
```

В самом коде порядок не такой и это просто отрывки